Joint optimization of a quadratic form with matrix and vector as optimization variables
I am trying to solve an optimization problem of the form:
$\underset{\mathbf{O}, \mathbf{s}}{max} \quad \mathbf{h}^{T} Diag(\mathbf{O}\mathbf{s}) \mathbf{P}^{-1} Diag(\mathbf{O}\mathbf{s}) \mathbf{h}$
$\text{subject to} \quad ||\mathbf{s}||_{2} = 1$
$\hspace{2.3cm}  \mathbf{O}\mathbf{O}^{T} = \mathbf{I}$
$\mathbf{P}$ is a known, positive definite matrix in $\mathbf{R}^{M \times M}$
$\mathbf{O}$ is an orthonormal matrix in $\mathbb{R}^{L \times M}$, with $L<M$
$\mathbf{s}$ is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^{M}$ and
$\mathbf{h}$ is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^{L}$.
$\text{Diag}(\cdot)$ refers to the operation that converts a vector into a diagonal matrix.
The difficulty I am facing is in trying to obtain the derivative with respect to $\mathbf{O}$, and the Lagrangian involving the constraints. Any simplifications or reformulations to the problem will be greatly valued.

It is not clear what the point of the $O$ matrix is.

If $O$ is orthogonal and $s$ is a unit vector, then $Os$ can be replaced by an arbitrary unit vector. You can probably find a unit vector that scales $h$ to be maximizing eigenvector of the quadratic form $x^T P^{-1}x$

@copper.hat I am trying to solve a problem where a high-dimensional vector $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{M}$ is compressed into $\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{O} \mathbf{x}$, where $\mathbf{y} \in \mathbb{R}^{L}$. Naturally $M>L$, which is why the matrix $\mathbf{O}$ appears in the question.

@whpowell96 I also considered the same approach. Does that mean that there is no unique solution to both $\mathbf{C}$ and $\mathbf{s}$?

I completely missed the $L<M$ part.
